# Count; find User with id= Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I am not sure why I am getting this Error when according to the tutorial everything should pass:

```
1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `show'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

My minitest:

require 'test_helper'

```
class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # add invalid information and test that the User.count never changes
  # also test that the sign up path is visited after invalid sign up
  test "invalid signup information" do
    # visit the signup path using get
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference "User.count" do
      post users_path, user: { name: "", email: "user@invalid", password: "foo", password_confirmation: "bar"}
    end
    assert_template "users/new"
  end  
end
```

I compared my users_controller to the official github tutorial and it looks the same

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    # strong parameters
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # handle save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I dont really understand why `id` is being searched for as well. My database is empty with no users. I am currently testing that inputing invalid parameters for sign up will not add another user.

my UserControllerTest:

require 'test_helper'

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: The test you posted is fine. The one failing is `UsersControllerTest`. If you attach it we can try to help you. Most likely you request user path with incorrect or missing id.

Comment: @makhan i'll take another look thanks!

Comment: @makhan i guess I put the code in the wrong part of the project. Thank you for pointing this out!!

Comment: add `user = User.create` before `get :show` and change `get :show` to `get :show, id: user.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show renders a page for specific user, so you need to pass it the id param. Change the test to:

```
  test "should get show" do
    user = User.create
    get :show, id: user.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

---

FYI, A small breakdown of the error message:

```
1) Error:
```

Error

```
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
```

In test `test_should_get_show` in class `UserControllerTest`

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

Database doesn't contain `User` object with empty `id`

```
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `show'
```

File and line that directly caused the error

```
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

File and line where the action originated from.