# ControllerTest error, Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, controller, fixtures

The Show action for my Controller is not passing the unit test.  I'm getting an error in my ControllerTest.   Here is the error I get from 'rake test':

```
> ERROR["test_should_get_show", TransactionsControllerTest, 2015-07-18
> 00:30:18 -0400]  test_should_get_show#TransactionsControllerTest
> (1437193818.29s) ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:        
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'=
>             app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:21:in `show'
>             test/controllers/transactions_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:TransactionsControllerTest>'
>         app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:21:in `show'
>         test/controllers/transactions_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:TransactionsControllerTest>'
> 
>   5/5:
> [=======================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
> 
> Finished in 0.24993s 5 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0
> skips
```

Despite this error, the view is successfully generates the page in the browser when I use this url:
http://localhost:3000/transactions/1

So, there is an error somewhere.  It's not failing.

**transactions_controller.rb**

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
    if @transaction.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @transactions = Transaction.all
  end

  def show
    @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])      #this is row 21
  end

    private
      def transaction_params
        params.require(:transaction).permit(:company, :month, :account_code, :description, :transaction_amount)
      end
end
```

**transaction_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class TransactionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get show" do
    transaction = Transaction.create
    get :show, id: transaction.id          #this is row 6
    assert_response :success 
  end

end
```

The following fixture was automatically generated by rails.  I'm new at rails and have to admit that I don't really understand fixtures.

**transactions.yml**

```
one:
  company: MyString
  month: 2015-06-19
  account_code: MyString
  description: MyString
  transaction_amount: 1.5

two:
  company: MyString
  month: 2015-06-19
  account_code: MyString
  description: MyString
  transaction_amount: 1.5
```

In my routes file, I'm setting the root to the index action.  I plan to access the show action via the url http://localhost:3000/transactions/1 and (as mentioned above) it actually works.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root            'transactions#index'
  resources       :transactions
end
```

**transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :month, presence: true 
    validates :account_code, presence: true
end
```

**transaction_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class TransactionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
        #@transaction = transactions(:one)
    @transaction = Transaction.new(company: "Inc", month: Date.new(2015,6,15).to_s, 
                                    account_code: "80-32100-12-1201-60010", 
                                    description: "Salaries & Wages - Histo Gross 1", transaction_amount: 100000)
    end

    test "should be valid" do
        assert @transaction.valid?
    end

    test "month should be present" do
    @transaction.month = "     "
    assert_not @transaction.valid?
  end

    test "account_code should be present" do
    @transaction.account_code = "     "
    assert_not @transaction.valid?
  end

  test "month cannot be a string" do      #not sure if this is worth anything at all
    @transaction.month = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    assert_not @transaction.valid?
  end


end
```

The test auto generated by Rails (before I modified it) was very simple:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TransactionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get show" do
    get :show   
    assert_response :success 
  end

end
```

I modified it to the current version above because (I believe) the test should first create a transaction and then reference id somehow.  But I'm not sure I did this correctly.

I've seen questions similar to this on Stackoverflow.  For instance, this question was helpful, but didn't quite get me there
[Count; find User with id= Minitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501279/count-find-user-with-id-minitest)

NOTE:  Initially, I set up the Controller incorrectly.  I set it up as a singular "TransactionController" and changed it to the plural "TransactionsController".  So I had to change the name in the unit test also.  Perhaps this has had an effect on the app.

So... questions:

1. why is the unit test failing while the show action is actually
   working in the browser?
2. How might I change the code in the unit test so it recognizes that
   I'm using transaction_params?
3. Do I have to modify the fixtures when I make changes to the
   unit_test or the controller?

Comment: can you try `Transaction.create!` please? Maybe you have a validation error and the transaction is not persisted in the DB

Comment: Interesting.   That now leads to the following error:  "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Month can't be blank, Account code can't be blank".  I'll post the model above.

Comment: So looks pretty clear now, right? :)

Comment: I would say that it's definitely not clear. :)    However, with a bit of research and trial and error I managed to get it to pass.  I will post my own answer, but it may take me the next 2 days to figure out what I did!

Comment: You are creating a transaction with no attributes, so the validation does not pass becasue month and account code are required. You must call Transaction.create(attributes) where attributes is an hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so coorasse's suggestion to use create! forced the app to uncover a validation error.  The initial error (Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'= ) was replaced with a new error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Month can't be blank,
>   Account code can't be blank

This was confusing because it leads me to think of a model validation error.  Why am I getting a model validation error in a ControllerTest?  Also, the transaction.rb model clearly shows that that I've added validations to satisfy the presence of Month and AccountCode.

So, I spent some time reading through "A Guide to Testing Rails Applications" on RailsGuides
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html
All the way down in Section 8, it shows how to include a block of code before each test.  Here is the new transaction_controller_test

**transaction_controller_test.rb (REVISED)**

```
require 'test_helper'

class TransactionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    # called before every single test
  def setup
    @transaction = transactions(:one)
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show, id: @transaction.id
    assert_response :success 
  end

end
```

After this the test passed!   Unfortunately, the RailsGuides doesn't tell me *why* I would want to use setup in a controller test.  If any smart Rails gurus has some guidance on this, your comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Models can raise an error when they are created with invalid attributes - it doesn't matter why or where the model is created